# Find index of last non-numeric character in String

Tags: java, string

Say I have a String made up of numbers, letters, and symbols,

```
String foo = "987abc<*(123";
```

How would I be able to find the index of the first number in the last *set* of numbers (`"1"`, at index `6`) in String `foo` – and if `foo = "123"`, I would get the index of that first number again (`"1"`, at index `0`). (And also have it return index `0` if `foo = ""`)

I'm pretty inexperienced with RegEx-es and search patterns like that, alongside the fact that every way I have tried hasn't worked properly (most of the time causing a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`).

*What's a reliable, simple way of finding the index of the start of the last set of numbers in a String?*

Comment: Start backwards and find if the prev char is not numeric, then you'll get the index & add + 1 to get the exact index

Comment: @neilharia7 What methods do I use to check if a character is non-numeric? I know how to iterate backwards over a string but the checks I've tried aren't working well. Is `!Character.isDigit(c)` the right way to go?

Comment: `!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))` `s`being the string

Comment: For an always correct way you need to take into account that a printing character, a code point, in the string may take up two indices. So the *reliable*  way doesn’t seem to be completely *simple*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
static int indexOfLastNumber(String s) {
    int removedLength = s.replaceFirst("\\d+\\D*$", "").length();
    return s.length() == removedLength ? 0 : removedLength;
}

static void test(String s) {
    System.out.println(s + " : " + indexOfLastNumber(s));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("987abc<*(123");
    test("987abc<*(123)");
    test("123");
    test("foo");
    test("");
}
```

output:

```
987abc<*(123 : 9
987abc<*(123) : 9
123 : 0
foo : 0
 : 0
```

or

```
static final Pattern LAST_NUMBER = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\D*$");

static int indexOfLastNumber(String s) {
    Matcher m = LAST_NUMBER.matcher(s);
    return m.find() ? m.start() : 0;
}
```

Comment: Worked great; thanks for the pattern! I adapted it a bit (by integrating the code in to my main method only) and there as been not a single issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Note: the '1' is at index 9 in your String.

If you don't want, it not necessary to use RegEx for this.

A method like this should do the job:

```java
public static int findLastNumbersIndex(String s) {
  boolean numberFound = false;
  boolean charBeforeNumberFound = false;

  //start at the end of the String
  int index = s.length() - 1;

  //loop from the back to the front while there are more chars 
  //and no nonDigit is found before a digit
  while (index >= 0 && !charBeforeNumberFound) {
    //when the first number was found, set the boolean flag
    if (!numberFound && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(index))) {
      numberFound = true;
    }

    //when already a number was found and there is any nonDigit stop the execution
    if (numberFound && !Character.isDigit(s.charAt(index))) {
      charBeforeNumberFound = true;
      break;
    }

    index--;
  }
   
  return index + 1;
}
```

The execution for different Strings:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("\"987abc<*(123\"" + " index of lastNumberSet: " + findLastNumbersIndex("987abc<*(123"));
  System.out.println("\"987abc<*(123abc\"" + " index of lastNumberSet: " + findLastNumbersIndex("987abc<*(123abc"));
  System.out.println("\"987abc\"" + " index of lastNumberSet: " + findLastNumbersIndex("987abc"));
  System.out.println("\"abc987\"" + " index of lastNumberSet: " + findLastNumbersIndex("abc987"));
  System.out.println("\"987\"" + " index of lastNumberSet: " + findLastNumbersIndex("987"));
  System.out.println("(Empty String)" + " index of lastNumberSet: " + findLastNumbersIndex(""));
  System.out.println("\"abc\"" + " index of lastNumberSet: " + findLastNumbersIndex("abc"));
}
```

returns this output:

```
"987abc<*(123" index of lastNumberSet: 9
"987abc<*(123abc" index of lastNumberSet: 9
"987abc" index of lastNumberSet: 0
"abc987" index of lastNumberSet: 3
"987" index of lastNumberSet: 0
(Empty String) index of lastNumberSet: 0
"abc" index of lastNumberSet: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using Regex named group

```java
public static int indexOfLastNumber(String text) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    return matcher.find() ? matcher.start() : -1;
}
```

and I used test cases from @csalmhof answer, thanks to him

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("\"987abc<*123\"" + " index of lastNumberSet: " + indexOfLastNumber("987abc<*123"));
    System.out.println("\"987abc<*123abc\"" + " index of lastNumberSet: " + indexOfLastNumber("987abc<*123abc"));
    System.out.println("\"987abc\"" + " index of lastNumberSet: " + indexOfLastNumber("987abc"));
    System.out.println("\"abc987\"" + " index of lastNumberSet: " + indexOfLastNumber("abc987"));
    System.out.println("\"987\"" + " index of lastNumberSet: " + indexOfLastNumber("987"));
    System.out.println("(Empty String)" + " index of lastNumberSet: " + indexOfLastNumber(""));
    System.out.println("\"abc\"" + " index of lastNumberSet: " + indexOfLastNumber("abc"));
}
```

Output, -1 for a text that has no numbers

```java
"987abc<*123" index of lastNumberSet: 8
"987abc<*123abc" index of lastNumberSet: 8
"987abc" index of lastNumberSet: 0
"abc987" index of lastNumberSet: 3
"987" index of lastNumberSet: 0
(Empty String) index of lastNumberSet: -1
"abc" index of lastNumberSet: -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern with a capture group, and if there is a match you can use [public int start(int group)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start-int-) to get the start index of the capture group of the Matcher.

```
(\d)\d*\D*$
```

- `(\d)` Capture a single digit in **group 1**
- `\d*` Match optional digits
- `\D*` Match optional non digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n6426S/1) and a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/TcevP3)

Example:

```
String[] strings = { "987abc<*(123", "", "123", "test", "abc123" };
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d)\\d*\\D*$");

for (String s : strings) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.printf("'%s' --> %d\n", s, matcher.start(1));
        continue;
    }
    System.out.printf("'%s' --> %d\n", s, 0);
}
```

Output

```
'987abc<*(123' --> 9
'' --> 0
'123' --> 0
'test' --> 0
'abc123' --> 3
```